# Filter array of objects by values when not all objects have some keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter an array of objects based on user input.

I wish filter based on the values of certain keys within the object. However, not all the objects have all keys inside them. This means when I check it throws an error.

How do I ignore if a particular object does not have one of the keys inside it and continues to output the matching objects?

Here is some sample data.

```
const data = [
{
    name: "John Miller",
    age: 33,
    location: "Chicago",
    address: '1 help street'
},

{
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: 78,
    address: '1 help me please lane'
},

{
    name: "Jamie Stevens",
    location: "San Diego",
    age: 32
}
]
```

The second object does not have 'location' as a key and the third object does not have 'address' as a key.

```
const handleSearch = (query) => {
    const keys = ['name', 'location', 'address']
    const filter =  data.filter((row) => (
      keys.some((key) => (row[key].toLowerCase().includes(query))
    )))
    setFilteredData(filter)
  }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine optional chaining with the nullish coalescing operator:

```
const handleSearch = (query) => {
  const keys = ['name', 'location', 'address']
  const filter = data.filter((row) => (
    keys.some((key) => {
        const k = row?.[key] ?? ''
        return (k.toLowerCase().includes(query))
      }
    )))
  setFilteredData(filter)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)(?.) and you also need to lower case the query:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "John Miller",
    age: 33,
    location: "Chicago",
    address: "1 help street",
  },

  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: 78,
    address: "1 help me please lane",
  },

  {
    name: "Jamie Stevens",
    location: "San Diego",
    age: 32,
  },
];

const handleSearch = (query) => {
  const keys = ["name", "location", "address"];
  const filtered = data.filter((row) =>
    keys.some((key) => { 
      return row[key]?.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())})
  );
  console.log(filtered);
};

handleSearch("Chicago")
```